# Asynchronous Javascript and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, client-side

I am still a newbie at JavaScript and have not done any internships or formal work on web development.

The HTML have 3 radio buttons and the h4 tag is for displaying some text/result based on radio button selection.

**HTML:**

```
<p>The 3 sages of the apocalypse</p>
<input id="cat" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Luceila of the South</label><br>
<input id="fav" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Isley of the North</label><br>
<input id="split" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Riful of the west</label><br>
    
<h4 id="display"></h4>
```

The lab requirements is such that I must use promises and when the promise object is rejected a different function call must take place. Promise is hard to understand as I have googled for 2 hours last week and cannot understand. What purpose does .then serve? Is it using the promise object?

**JavaScript (not working):**

```
$('input[type=radio][name=3sages]').change(function()
{
    function wrong()
    {
        const write = document.getElementById("display");
        write.innerHTML = "Wrong";
    }

    function correct()
    {
        const write = document.getElementById("display");
        write.innerHTML = "He is my favorite";
    }

    let guarantee = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        if ($('#fav').is(':checked'))
        {
            resolve(correct());
        }
        else
        {
            reject(wrong());
        }
    });

    guarantee.then( 
        function() 
        {
            correct();
        },
        function() 
        {
            wrong();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: the first function in .then is called with the resolved value of the Promise (the second function, if used, is called with the rejected value of the promise)

Comment: your code as such wouldn't need Promise at all - since the only asynchrony is introduced by having a Promise in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JavaScript (not working)

Actually your code works fine (but read on). Make sure you include jQuery, and that your script is executed after the document has loaded - so place your script at the bottom of the page. Here is your code in your runnable snippet:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=3sages]').change(function()
{
    function wrong()
    {
        const write = document.getElementById("display");
        write.innerHTML = "Wrong";
    }

    function correct()
    {
        const write = document.getElementById("display");
        write.innerHTML = "He is my favorite";
    }

    let guarantee = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        if ($('#fav').is(':checked'))
        {
            resolve(correct());
        }
        else
        {
            reject(wrong());
        }
    });

    guarantee.then( 
        function() 
        {
            correct();
        },
        function() 
        {
            wrong();
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The 3 sages of the apocalypse</p>
<input id="cat" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Luceila of the South</label><br>
<input id="fav" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Isley of the North</label><br>
<input id="split" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Riful of the west</label><br>
    
<h4 id="display"></h4>
```

> I must use promises

Honestly, it makes no sense to use promises when there is no asynchronous behaviour. In your code the promise is created at a moment that all needed information is available, and there is nothing to await asynchronously.

If this is indeed the intended exercise, so be it, but if you want to look to something that really **is** asynchronous then look to awaiting the user's input. That part is asynchronous -- you don't know beforehand when the user will click that radio button. That is where a promise can be used. This comes down to *promisifying* the jQuery `.click` method (or more generally, its `.on` method). As a promise is about capturing one event, and event listeners trigger on *each* repeated event, you would need to only listen to one event (using jQuery's `.one` method) and then when it fires, create a new promise for the next event occurrence.

Here is how that would look:

```js
// Generic function to get a promise of a certain event on a selected element
function promiseEvent(selector, event) {
    return new Promise(resolve => $(selector).one(event, resolve));
}

// Specific function to get a promise for the user selecting an answer
function promiseAnswer() {
    return promiseEvent('input[type=radio][name=3sages]', 'change');
}

// Create the promise and listen for when it resolves
promiseAnswer().then(processChoice);

function processChoice() {
    // React to the user's choice
    $("#display").text(
        $('#fav').is(':checked') ? "He is my favorite" : "Wrong"
    );
    // Create the promise again and listen when it resolves
    promiseAnswer().then(processChoice);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The 3 sages of the apocalypse</p>
<input id="cat" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Luceila of the South</label><br>
<input id="fav" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Isley of the North</label><br>
<input id="split" type="radio" name="3sages">
<label >Riful of the west</label><br>
    
<h4 id="display"></h4>
```

Comment: I did some cross checking with JSFiddle, it is as you said my code works. It turns out my chrome browser have some issues. Will just ask my tutor what went wrong. Thanks regardless for sharing your though process for some inspiration and learning

Comment: Just added $(document).ready( function() ... and it works on chrome browser, *facepalm*

Comment: Thought so. That's why I suggested to put your script at the bottom of the page. But `ready` also works. However in jQuery best practice, you'd use the shorter `$(function()...`. Still I prefer to just put the script at the end of the document.